# Tomcat heap dump creation

Tags: java, tomcat

In our Environment the tomcat server got hanged frequently then we increase the heap and restart the tomcat.

There is any another way to analyze the heap dumps in tomcat??
can we create the heap dumps in tomcat? if possible how?

Thanks
Surya

Answer (score 1):

First, you should analyze exactly what causes your Tomcat to hang. There are many reasons which can cause an application to "hang", e.g. dead locks, long GC pauses, etc.

Looking at the heap dump makes sense if your Tomcat crashes with an `OutOfMemoryError`.
In that case you can use a tool like [MAT](http://www.eclipse.org/mat/) to analyze the heap dump.

You can create heap dumps any time with `jcmd <pid> GC.heap_dump <file>`. You can also set the VM option `-XX:+HeapDumpOnOutOfMemoryError`. This will dump the heap automatically when you get an `OutOfMemoryError`.